# Clickhouse insert json data to string column

Tags: python, postgresql, clickhouse

We need to insert data from postgres to clickhouse. One of the field in postgres has json type.
In clickhouse this field has Nullable(String) type.
For inserting data we use *Airflow ClickHouse Plugin*:

```
 data = postgress_hook.get_records(query)     
 clickhouse_hook.run(
                    sql="INSERT INTO "+ self.clickhouse_tgt_table +" values",
                    parameters=data
 )
```

But we have an error during inserting:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

What clickhouse type should we use to store json data?

Comment: could you provide a detailed description of the error (with *call stack*)? Are you sure that *query* has type *str* not *dict*?

Comment: i think you should serialise the json data before inserting it in clickhouse, and it will probably work. Blindly just from your error message i would say you read the json data from postgress to a dict, and when trying to write it to clickhouse, your python code is trying to serialise it (encode) and it doesn't find a way to serialise a dict. But. maybe i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

this message is not from CH server, but from a python driver.